# ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync() return “Access is denied”

Tags: uwp, voice-recognition

I am trying to activate the microphone on my Desktop PC (Windows 10) to implement some voice recognition code. Here is my simple out of the box UWP app:

The call to `ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync()`
is throwing:

`ex = {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.`

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        initializeSpeechRecognizer();
    }

    // Initialize Speech Recognizer and start async recognition
    private async void initializeSpeechRecognizer()
    {
        // Initialize recognizer
        mRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

        // Load Grammer file constraint
        string fileName = String.Format(SRGS_FILE);
        var path = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        StorageFile grammarContentFile = await path.GetFileAsync(fileName);

        SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint grammarConstraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(grammarContentFile);

        // Add to grammer constraint
        mRecognizer.Constraints.Add(grammarConstraint);

        // Compile grammer
        SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult compilationResult = await mRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine("Status: " + compilationResult.Status.ToString());
        Debug.WriteLine("Result: " + compilationResult.ToString());
    }

    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await mRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I have added the `Microphone` to the Manifest Capabilities.
The microphone on my Desktop is active and working.
My current Language is en-US, which is listed in the SupportedTopicLanguages
and SupportedGrammarLanguages properties.
Visual Studio 2017 is running in Administrator Mode.

Comment: Found the issue:      Some speech recognition features require acceptance of the Microsoft Privacy Policy. Information about this privacy policy can be found in the Settings app, under Privacy -> Speech, Inking and Typing. You must view the privacy policy in order to accept it. To view the privacy policy, press the Privacy Policy link on the Speech, Inking and Typing settings page.

Comment: You should post your solution as the answer to this question to help others find it :-)